# Why the p-values of a zero-inflation model are not useful, and how do we know statistically significance?

Tags: p-value, zero-inflation

We are talking about zero-inflated negative binomial models.

In [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619892/interpretation-of-glmmtmb-output-for-zero-inflated-negative-binomial-regression) [Ben Bolker](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2126/ben-bolker) said:

> The p-value in the zero-inflation term is not really useful (and should probably be eliminated from the model summary); it compares the coefficient (log-odds of zero-inflation) to a reference value of zero, which would correspond to 50% zero-inflation — not really a meaningful value.)

1. Why the p-values are not useful?
2. Is "log-odds of zero inflation" the same as "log-odds of obtaining a structural zero"?
3. Why the reference value is 0?
4. Why that reference value corresponds to 50% zero-inflation?
5. Why is it not a meaningful value?
6. How do we know whether a variable is statistically significant in predicting the probability to obtain a structural zero?

EDIT: [This package](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/p_value.zcpglm.html) purports to compute the p-values of zero-inflated models, including the ones of the zero-inflation component. So is it
useless?

EDIT 2: [Related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474561/how-to-get-p-values-for-the-zero-inflated-part-of-a-model)

EDIT 3: [Related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481951/what-is-the-best-method-to-determine-significance-in-a-zero-inflated-poisson-mod)

Answer (score 4):

> Why the p-values are not useful?

As Ben says, the p-value corresponds to comparing the coefficient to a reference value of 0. A 0 on log odds scale corresponds to 50% probability of structural zero. Unless you have some extremely specific scenario in which 50% probability of structural zero is actually important, e.g. something to do with flipping unbiased coins, this is unlikely to be meaningful.

> Is "log-odds of zero inflation" the same as "log-odds of obtaining a structural zero"?

Yes.

> Why the reference value is 0?

Convention. You can compare the coefficient with any reference value if you code the test by hand, but `summary` commands will generally compare it with 0.

> Why that reference value corresponds to 50% zero-inflation?

The zero-inflation part of the model, models log-odds of the mean as a linear function of predictors. The formula for log-odds is

$$
\text{log odds} = \log(\pi/(1-\pi))
$$

If you have $\text{log odds}=0$, and rearrange the above formula to solve for $\pi$, you will find $\pi=0.5$, i.e. the 50% chance of a structural zero.

> Why is it not a meaningful value?

See first response.

> How do we know whether a variable is statistically significant in predicting the probability to obtain a structural zero?

In the linked question, it says *Testing for zero-inflation is tricky; the simplest (although crude and conservative) way to test the importance of zero-inflation would be to compare AIC values or do a likelihood ratio test*. To elaborate, including zero-inflation is actually changing the inherent structure of the response variable. This differs from something like testing a parameter for significance in a linear model. It's more akin to the question "is my response Gaussian, or Gamma?"

I would suggest a combination of AIC and visual inspection is good for determining if a zero-inflation is required. The R DHARMa package also provides a zero-inflation check, and some model suitability plotting functions.

If you *really* need to report significance, then you could do the likelihood ratio test as Ben suggests. I don't suggest doing significance tests unless there is a formal hypothesis you wish to answer.

If you have already determined that zero-inflation is a necessary part of the model, there are situations in which the p-value *would* be useful. For example, let's say your zero-inflation formula is `~ x` where `x` has values "Control" and "Impact". Then `x = "Control"` would be the baseline level of zero-inflation, and the coefficient for `x = "Impact"` would be "what is the additional zero-inflation due to being in the Impact group". In that case, examining the p-value for Impact would tell you if the Impact group affects the chance of a structural zero.

Comment: I support this answer. My only nit-pick is that the reason that log-likelihood and AIC values are imperfect (conservative, i.e. you are too likely to conclude that you do *not* need to include zero-inflation) is a technical issue (that the null value lies on the boundary of the feasible space), not that adding zero-inflation is somehow qualitatively different from testing a regression parameter. The qualitative difference is that a regression parameter (null value 0) can be negative or positive, while a probability (null value 0) can't be negative.

Comment: For edit 1 (the methods for the `parameters` package for `cplm` models): again supporting the current answer: the test of the *intercept* of the zero-inflation model is (usually) useless, but tests of the effects of covariates on the Z-I probability may be useful.

Comment: This article (https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/) interpret the zero inflation model saying: "The log odds of being an excessive zero would decrease by 1.67 for every additional person in the group. In other words, the more people in the group the less likely that the zero would be due to not gone fishing. Put plainly, the larger the group the person was in, the more likely that the person went fishing.". So this paragraph is wrong, right?

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: @robertspierre the example in your linked article is similar to the part of my answer where I say "there are situations in which the p-value would be useful." It's not wrong.

Comment: oh, so Ben was talking about the p-value __of the intercept term__ of the zero inflated model. Why did you not specify that? I understood that all p-values were useless.

Comment: The [original post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619892/interpretation-of-glmmtmb-output-for-zero-inflated-negative-binomial-regression) linked in the question was referring to an intercept-only term; I thought we were talking about that. But my last paragraph also talks about a situation when the p-value _is_ useful.